# error shown in jsp form when using errors tag

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am developing a project 'form validation' using Spring framework in eclipse.In the jsp page for form creation shows error when include  tag.when mouse over it shows "Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be 
     parameterized"

myform.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration Page</title>
<style>
.error {
    color: #ff0000;
    font-style: italic;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="POST" commandName="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter User Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Degree :</td>
            <td><form:input path="degree" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="degree" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Mark :</td>
            <td><form:input path="mark" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="mark" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Address :</td>
            <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="address" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Mail ID :</td>
            <td><form:input path="mail" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="mail" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

validation.java:

```
package com.validation;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;



import com.validation.Student;

public class StudentValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Student.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name",
                "name.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "degree",
                "degree.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "mark", "mark.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "address", "address.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "mail",
                "mail.required");

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Student user = (Student) target;

    }

}
```

can anyone tell what is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't see a `include` tag nor do I see `List` being used anywhere in the code which you have shared. Which line are you seeing the error exactly? And Raw types should only be a warning and not an error.

Comment: Thats the problem..I didnt used any List.. the warning line is..         <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>

Comment: Since it's just a warning, can you try and run it and see what happens? Try cleaning the project and building it again and try removing that line to see if it works.. I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: its running successfully..if that lines are removed it didnt shows error message.... thanks for your help